# Is there a way to use excel to graph where data points fall in according to an optimal range?

Tags: excel, graph, range

I am using excel and want to make a graph that shows where data points fall in according to an optimal range. In my case, I receive soil tests that show the percent Nitrogen, Phosphorous and Potassium. Each element has it's optimal range for the soil and I am trying to make a formula that I can paste in the data from the soil test and it will graph where the data falls within the optimal ranges of each particular element.

For example:
Nitrogen's optimal range is between 2 and 2.8%
If a soil test comes back that says 2.4, I want a formula that will convert that to where it is between the optimal range (in the middle). If the Nitrogen is 1.5 I want it to graph it showing that it is below the optimal range.

Each element has a different range, some optimal ranges have a lot larger range that is optimal than in the example above, like the optimal range could be from 3-500ppm.

I'm lost with how to do this so hoping to find some help! I have been graphing it manually and it would be a huge help if I can automate this more.

Comment: Somewhat vague. Yes, you can generate graphs with Excel, but they are neither flexible nor easy to automate. If you aren't wedded to Excel, consider using R instead.

Comment: @JohnColeman Excel charts are very flexible. How easy they are to automate compared to using R depends on the familiarity with R or Excel/VBA. Bryce, have you considered using Bullet Charts? Google them. If not, please edit your question and give some indication about what the chart should look like. One chart per value? Several values in one chart? Mock something up with the drawing tools or photograph a sketch. Also post some sample data. Then we at least know what to aim for.